# Have a Python index error on splitlines function

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, index-error

The following Python code is giving me an index error at Line 17, version = result[marker:].splitlines()[0]:

```
import os, math, sys

#OS_bit = (round(math.log(sys.maxint,2)+1)) # get the bit

os.system("sudo apt-get install python-pip && sudo apt-get install tor") # installing dependencies
os.system("pip install -U selenium")
os.system("pip install Pysocks")
os.system("pip install pyvirtualdisplay && apt-get install xvfb")

#print("\n \n {} \n \n".format(OS_bit))

os.system('firefox -v > tmp') 
result = open('tmp', 'r').read()
print (result)
marker = result.find('Firefox') + 8 
print (marker)
version = result[marker:].splitlines()[0] 
print (version)
a,b,c = version.split(".") 
os.remove('tmp')
```

version = result[marker:].splitlines()[0]

IndexError: list index out of range

Not sure how to address. Any quick lessons one could share? Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of your `print`s for each of the component parts? (`marker` and `result`)

Comment: result does not output anything, whereas marker gives 7. I assume since result is empty, the marker index is out of range. I do not know why result is empty, however.

Comment: @Abagnale If result doesn't print anything that means there's nothing to go ahead, and indexing at result will throw an error.
Also the marker is giving 7 as output because result.find('Firefox') returns -1. Check the file you're trying to read, conventions etc for your first step

Comment: Yes, tmp is empty, but unsure as to why firefox -v isn't passing anything to tmp.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with result, result is not a list it's just an assignment variable, so that's why you're seeing that `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Answer (score 0):

Splitlines returns a list and you are accessing the first element within this list. The reason for your error is that `string.splitlines()` returns an empty list.

```
>>> string = ""
>>> string.splitlines()
[]
>>> string.splitlines()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: In his comment he said that ```print(result)``` doesnt output anything. And @SauravJoshi mentioned that the ```find()``` returns -1 which indicates that result is empty

Comment: true, but you can't index -1, that's not a `list` or something that can be indexed by doing `[marker:]` so the error is with the `result` since it returns nothing in it

Comment: Yes, why is firefox -v not passing anything to tmp?